# Irregularly spaced columns in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table, spacing

I am trying to create a table that's divided into to sections with 2 headings; one on top and one bottom. The top section will have 3 headings and 3 columns(`<td>`s). The second will have one long heading, 2 columns, and one long footer. I am having trouble getting the 2 bottom columns to span the length of the table (they are currently aligned with the first 2 columns on the upper section.
[image]

I've tried using `colspan="1.5" (my logic is if the colspan="3", then half will work) as well as width="550px;" (the full width of the table is 1000px). Any suggestions here on what I do to achieve this? Code is below (Note: this is a javascript app that uses a DOM Node to dynamically create the table; I'm just using inline css to get it in there right now).

```
supplemental_dialog.innerHTML = "<h6>Map Date: " + this_date + "</h6>" + 
        "<div class='row' style='height:100px;'>" +
        "<div><h5>Location Information</h5>" +
        "<table id='table2' width=100%>" +
        "<tr width=100%>" +
        "<th><b>Flood Event</b></th>" + "<th><b>Estimated Flood Depth*</b></th>" + "<th><b>Estimated Base Flood Elevation*</b></th>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "<tr width=100%>" +
        "<td width=33%>0.2 Percent (500 Year)</td><td width=33%>" + "14.5 feet above land surface" + "</td>" + "<td width=33%>" + "496.4 feet NAVD 1988" + "</td > " +
        "</tr>" +
        "<tr width=100%>" +
        "<td width=33%>0.2 Percent (500 Year)</td><td width=33%>" + "14.5 feet above land surface" + "</td>" + "<td width=33%>" + "496.4 feet NAVD 1988" + "</td > " +
        "</tr>" +
        "<tr width=100%>" +
        "<td width=33%>0.2 Percent (500 Year)</td><td width=33%>" + "14.5 feet above land surface" + "</td>" + "<td width=33%>" + "496.4 feet NAVD 1988" + "</td > " +
        "</tr>" +
        "<tr width=100%>" +
        "<td width=33%>0.2 Percent (500 Year)</td><td width=33%>" + "14.5 feet above land surface" + "</td>" + "<td width=33%>" + "496.4 feet NAVD 1988" + "</td > " +
        "</tr>" +
        "<tr width=100%>" +
        "<th colspan='3' width=100% style='text-align:center'><b>Probability of Flooding </b></td>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "<tr width=100%>" +
        "<td width='500px'>0.2 Percent (500 Year)</td><td width='500px'>" + "14.5 feet above land surface" + "</td>" + 
        "</tr>" +
        "<tr width=100%>" +
        "<td width='500px'>0.2 Percent (500 Year)</td><td width='500px'>" + "14.5 feet above land surface" + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "<tr width=100%>" +
        "<td colspan='3' width=100%><p style='font-size: 10px;'>*The information included in this report is based on the entire building footprint, or, if clicked outside of a building footprint, based on the point clicked on the map.  Results are not considered an official determination.</p></td>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "</table></div > " +
        "</div>";
```

To be clear; this is my goal:
[image]

Comment: shouldn't be colspan='2' ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that makes the first column 2 columns wide (aligns with the second column in the upper section) and the second column is aligned with just the third column in the upper section.

Comment: you must also add colspan='1' for the first column's row

Comment: Nope; same result as above.

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML rather than a JavaScript statement that doesn't run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one easy way here is by adding proper colspan values for different cells in different rows
see the example :

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">first col</th>
      <th colspan="2">second col</th>
      <th colspan="2">third col</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">a</td>
      <td colspan="2">b</td>
      <td colspan="2">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">d</td>
      <td colspan="3">e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">f</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This solution is not quite what I am looking for. I added an additional picture at the bottom of my original post to illustrate what I need. Basically I want the bottom 2 columns to be evenly sized and break in the middle of the table.

Comment: Note that the topic starter uses a `<table width=100%>` If using a margin, padding or border, this will result in a table greater then 100%. Avoid this by using only padding and/or border with `table, table * { box-sizing: border-box; }` or in general `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`

Comment: I updated my example, there are other ways too

Comment: Yessss! Making the colspan=6 and dividing accordingly did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. If you want the css as an inline `style="..."` then change this in the way you like.

```css
#table2 {
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#table2 tr {
    width: 100%;
}
#table2 th, #table2 td {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
#table2 th {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table id='table2'>
    <tr>
        <th width="33%"><b>Flood Event</b></th>
        <th width="33%"><b>Estimated Flood Depth*</b></th>
        <th width="33%"><b>Estimated Base Flood Elevation*</b></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0.2 Percent (500 Year)</td>
        <td>14.5 feet above land surface</td>
        <td>496.4 feet NAVD 1988</td > 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0.2 Percent (500 Year)</td>
        <td>14.5 feet above land surface</td>
        <td>496.4 feet NAVD 1988</td > 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3"><b>Probability of Flooding </b></th>
        <th style="display: none;" width='0%'></th> 
        <th style="display: none;" width='0%'></th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" width='50%'>0.2 Percent (500 Year)</td>
        <td width='50%'>14.5 feet above land surface</td> 
        <td style="display: none;" width='0%'></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" width='50%'>0.2 Percent (500 Year)</td>
        <td width='50%'>14.5 feet above land surface</td>
        <td style="display: none;" width='0%'></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr width=100%>
        <td colspan='3' width=100%>
        <p style='font-size: 10px; text-align:center;'>*The information included in this report is based on the entire building footprint, or, if clicked outside of a building footprint, based on the point clicked on the map.  Results are not considered an official determination.</p></td>
        <td style="display: none;" width='0%'></td> 
        <td style="display: none;" width='0%'></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your image, it is evident that you need to represent your data in **two tables**. Context matters, you have two headers which serve to identify the information in each of the rows.

Note that the first table is a regular table, meaning the same number of columns per row, the second is irregular. I have wrapped the table in HTML5 syntax and used CSS to provide the look and feel you are aiming for in the image.

```css
table, tr, td {
  text-align: center;
}

td, th {
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  background-color: #0A4386;
  color: white;
}

.regular-table {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.irregular-table {
  border-top: 0;
}

.footer {
  font-size: 12px
}
```

```html
<table class="regular-table" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">first header</th>
        <th colspan="2">second header</th>
        <th colspan="2">third header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">first content</td>
        <td colspan="2">second content</td>
        <td colspan="2">third content</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="irregular-table" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="12">some header message goes here</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="6">first content</td>
        <td colspan="6">second content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="footer">
        <td colspan="12">* some long overdue footer content goes here</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the flexible way, no colspan or table related structure problems.

Be aware that browsers include the `<tbody>` if you did leave it out your html. So include always the tbody.

Simply specify a `max-width` to specify the width of each column. That's all.

```css
table, tr {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
tbody, th, td {
  display: block;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
th, td {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  font: normal 14px/1.4 sans-serif;
}
th {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id='table2' style='max-width: 100%'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style='max-width: 33%'><b>Flood Event</b></th>
      <th style='max-width: 33%'><b>Estimated Flood Depth*</b></th>
      <th style='max-width: 34%'><b>Estimated Base Flood Elevation*</b></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style='max-width: 33%'>0.2 Percent (500 Year)</td>
      <td style='max-width: 33%'>14.5 feet above land surface</td>
      <td style='max-width: 34%'>496.4 feet NAVD 1988</td > 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style='max-width: 33%'>0.2 Percent (500 Year)</td>
      <td style='max-width: 33%'>14.5 feet above land surface</td>
      <td style='max-width: 34%'>496.4 feet NAVD 1988</td > 
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <th style='max-width: 100%'><b>Probability of Flooding </b></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style='max-width: 50%'>0.2 Percent (500 Year)</td>
      <td style='max-width: 50%'>14.5 feet above land surface</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style='max-width: 50%'>0.2 Percent (500 Year)</td>
      <td style='max-width: 50%'>14.5 feet above land surface</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style='max-width: 100%'>
      <p style='font-size: 10px; text-align:center;'>*The information included in this report is based on the entire building footprint, or, if clicked outside of a building footprint, based on the point clicked on the map.  Results are not considered an official determination.</p></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```